# Reorder TableView Cells With NSFetchedResultsController Core Data - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, swift3

I am using an NSFetchedResultsController. I can't find any straightforward tutorials that walk through it for `Swift 3`.

So here is what I have done so far. I have successfully populated my table using an `NSFetchedResultsController` that fetches the inserted data from core data. I created an attribute in my core data model called, `orderPosition` that is declared as `Int32`. I haven't done anything with this attribute in regards to adding and saving data to core data upon insert.

In my fetch `func` where I initialize the `NSFetchedResultsController`, I have modified my sort descriptor to include the following code:

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "orderPosition", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
```

Then I implemented the `tableView` func:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    attemptFetch()
    var objects = self.controller.fetchedObjects! 
    self.controller.delegate = nil

    let object = objects[sourceIndexPath.row]
    objects.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    objects.insert(object, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

    var i = 0
    for object in objects {
        object.setValue(i += 1, forKey: "orderPosition")
    }

    appdel.saveContext()
    self.controller.delegate = self

}
```

In my implementation of the `didChange` anObject func, I included the switch-case for `.insert`, `.delete`, `.update`, and `.move`. 
My `.move` case looks like the following:

```
case.move:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        break
```

Please help me figure this out. I have been spending weeks trying to understand this. I have gone through many if not all stack overflow questions on this. I implemented some of the loop ideas from one because I had a similar thought process to approach this but it didn't work. There are no Swift 3 core data tutorials/videos that I have come across that will really help me solve and understand this well. I don't want to give up on this.

Comment: I retracted the flag , Unfortunately I don't code in Swift. However,  this might be an outdated tutorial , but maybe you can get a hint from it unless nobody provides you with a solution other than the duplicate link I provided earlier. http://www.iosnomad.com/blog/2014/8/6/swift-nsfetchedresultscontroller-trickery

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look. It's been frustrating but I am determined to figure this out with this.

Comment: @JoséNeto I want to implement tableview reordering where I can click edit, move cells around, click done and have it save the new order and persist with my core data model. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Sneak Thank you for the link. I have gone through this "...Trickery" tutorial multiple times, trying to understand it. Unfortunately, it is really advanced.

Comment: Well, everything you need for reordering etc is provided there, I don't think you will get an "easy way out" . Did you check out the sample project he provided? https://github.com/MrAlek/Swift-NSFetchedResultsController-Trickery The complete source code is there for you .BTw, it seems he even updated it for **Xcode8 and Swift 3** for you! :)

Comment: @Sneak I did check out the project but its split up in many classes and with many additional aspects that was making it a little confusing for me. Honestly, I am not looking for an "easy way out." I just want to achieve this at a basic level with guidance. Like I said, I have tried to understand these advanced tutorials and github source code projects with no luck. Thank you for your help though. I keep looking at that tutorial over and over thinking something more will click. I kindof get what hes doing but every time I try to implement, it doesn't work out.

Comment: @Sneak You and I have similar approaches to learning. I always try to break a project to get a deeper understanding. Don't worry I haven't given up on doing that. As I am typing this, I have it open and am trying to go over Haha thanks again, I really appreciate you trying to help me with this.

Comment: @Sneak I'm so close. My app is visually reordering and not crashing but it's not saving and persisting the reorder.

Comment: @Sneak Thanks, Yeah so that's what I'm not understanding...my sort descriptor is working but my appdel.saveContext() is not saving the new order. I know you aren't a swift dev but any idea what I might be missing. In my For loop I made it .setValue(NSNumber(i += 1), forKey: "orderPosition"). I know I'm extremely close.

Comment: @Sneak unfortunately my rep is not high enough for chat. No worries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136652/discussion-between-sneak-and-devspace).

Answer (score 8):

Just implemented similar functionality in my project.Turned out to be easier than it seemed.

Here is an update for your `moveRowAt` method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    // NOT NEEDED, SINCE I ASSUME THAT YOU ALREADY FETCHED ON INITIAL LOAD
    // attemptFetch()

    var objects = self.controller.fetchedObjects! 

    // NOT NEEDED
    //self.controller.delegate = nil

    let object = objects[sourceIndexPath.row]
    objects.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    objects.insert(object, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

    // REWRITEN BELOW
    //var i = 0
    //for object in objects {
    //    object.setValue(i += 1, forKey: "orderPosition")
    //}

    for (index, item) in items.enumerated() {
        item.orderPosition = index
    }

    appdel.saveContext()
    //self.controller.delegate = self

}
```

In `didChange` technically you don't need any code. The table is updated in place, when you move the item in it. And your data in coreData is updated when you save the context. So next time the data is fetched, based on the sortDescriptor you have, it will come in sorted by orderPosition.

Worked for me. Let me know, if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3):

Swift deviates from C in that the =, += and other assignment-like operations returns `Void`.  So your line `object.setValue(i += 1, forKey: "orderPosition")` is setting `i` to be one more but is always setting the position to be 0. Try instead:

```
var i = 0
for object in objects {
    i += 1
    object.setValue(i, forKey: "orderPosition")
}
```

or if you want to simplify your code a bit you can do

```
for (i, object) in objects.enumerated() {
    object.setValue(i, forKey: "orderPosition")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Moving around:

```
    var objects = frc.fetchedObjects!

    // Disable fetchedresultscontroller updates.

    let obj objects.remove(at: indexPath.item)
    objects.insert(obj, at: newIndexPath)

    for (i, obj) in objects.enumerated() {
        obj.orderIndex = Int32(i)
    }

    // Enable fetchedresultscontroller updates.

    context.saveContext()
```

#### TLDR: Disable updates from the fetchedresultscontroller cause else things crash on you, or use a workaround which does not crash on you.

#### My full tale on why to lock.

The disable stuff is there cause the tableview moved the cell already. If you then set the orderIndex, it will try to move things again which might crash on you as it did on me.

My workaround to this is to not have a .move case

```
    case .update, .move:
        print("update")
        self.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
```

which I do not need anyway cause I move only with the tableview for now. If you want to have the fetchedresultscontroller move stuff too you have to not have this case .update, .move but handle the .move yourself like

```
    case .move:
        print("move")
        self.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
```

but don't forget to implement the locking or my alternative below then.

Another workaround to not crash on me on endUpdates was

```
    if let toIndexPath = newIndexPath {
        if type == .update && toIndexPath != indexPath!{
            print("it should be a move.")
            print("move")
            self.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
            return
        }
    }
```

which detects updates for which newIndexPath != indexPath(the old index path), essentially it detects moves which are not declared as moves and fixed the problem for me too, but it was just too weird for me.

The following is the fetchedresultscontrollers' answer to my orderIndex changes, which should explain why you, incase you want to have the fetchedresultscontroller move stuff to better implement my "move disguised as update" detection or disable updates to table during the updating of the objects, which is fine cause the table reordered cells itself already by your move.

```
    from: Optional([0, 2])
    to: Optional([0, 1])
    update
    from: Optional([0, 1])
    to: Optional([0, 0])
    update
    from: Optional([0, 0])
    to: Optional([0, 2])
    move
    ... Assertion failure in ...
    attempt to perform an insert and a move to the same index path (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000400016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2})
    (null)
```

edit:

I think the "move disguised as update" detection does not produce crap cause it simply reloads all the cells. Cause then it moved the tableviewcell 1 time by the tableview itself + 3 times by the detection(useless).

Why is fetchedresultscontroller using this call-pattern? It probably frantically tries to get the table in order as if the updates came from outside and the table needs updating. But it does not know that the table cells got put in the right order already by the tableview, so it crashes hard on super.endUpdates() for some reason.

SOO: probably most simple solution is to disable updates to the tableview. How? No idea right now, I'm going to bed.

Comment: I set frc.delegate to nil to "Disable fetchedresultscontroller update" and then set it to self to reenable them in the tableView:moveRowAt method and it works.  Great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming core data & fetchedResultsController: regarding moveRowAt, the from and to index path rows are within the section.
If you are moving between the sections you need to work out the actual row to move in your array. ie: if you are moving the second row in the third section to the second row in the first section you actually need to know how many rows there are in all the sections to remove the correct row and insert at the correct place.

I use the following method to get the correct rows:-

```
    // Do not trigger delegate methods when changes are made to core data by the user
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil
        var fromIndex = fromIndexPath.row
        var toIndex = toIndexPath.row
        //      print ("from row ",fromIndexPath.row)
//work out correct row to remove at based on it's current row and section
        for sectionIndex in 0..<fromIndexPath.section
        {
            fromIndex += fetchedResultsController.sections![sectionIndex].numberOfObjects
        }
            //print ("fromIndex ",fromIndex)
// remove the row at it's old position
       toDoData.remove(at: fromIndex)
//work out the correct row to insert at based on which section it's going to & row in that section
        for sectionIndex in 0..<toIndexPath.section
        {
            toIndex += fetchedResultsController.sections![sectionIndex].numberOfObjects
            //print ("toIndex ",toIndex)
            if sectionIndex == fromIndexPath.section
            {
                toIndex -= 1 // Remember, controller still thinks this item is in the old section
                //print ("-= toIndex",toIndex)
            }
        }
// put the item back into he array at new position
         toDoData.insert(item, at: toIndex)
```

Note: toDoData is my array of records from the fetchedResultsController